# Is gradually translating a program written in C++ to Python feasible?

Tags: c++, python, translation, boost-python

This is simply a personal exercise/project, I don't intend to inflict this on the world. My goal is to further my understanding of both languages, and it would be a nice having a nice Python code base in the end.

But basically there is a program I like with a large (about 100ksloc) C++ code base, what I'd like to do is gradually rewrite modules in Python while having the existing C++ code use the new Python. The reason I'd like to do it this way instead of starting from scratch is because the application would/should be fully functional from the beginning.

Prime question is: Is this realistic? I'm pretty sure it'd work in theory, but in practice is it just not worth the effort?

Has anyone done it before?

Comment: Try asking a specific question. Has it been done? Yes. Is it "feasible"? That's a matter of opinion, and depends on your resources and abilities.

Answer (score 4):

> having the existing C++ code use the new Python

I think you'll find that python makes a better glue language for C++ than C++ does for python.  So you probably will have an easier time converting the main function to python first (in fact, the first step could be just renaming the `main` function, compiling the C++ app as a python library, and having one line of python which calls the renamed `main`).  Then start moving functionality from C++ to python one line at a time.

As @freedompeace suggested, you may want to leave significant chunks in C++, with python providing the glue.  Depends on whether portability or speed/memory efficiency is more important to you.

Comment: Isn't embedding involved to some extent either way? If I went your route how would new Python code interact with the existing code? Sounds like it'd be more akin to a rewrite than a gradual phaseout. Say I call main() from Python and I rewrote the protocol stuff in Python. It'd still be using the C++ code, I'd have to write my own main function in which case I have the I have the protocol and nothing else because the C++ wouldn't be able to interact with it, the problem is repeated until eventually I've replaced the entire app. Or am I missing something? Hard to express myself with the char li

Comment: @Josef: It's always easier to call a compiled language from a dynamic one.  You're fixated on rewriting leaf functions first.  What I'm suggesting is to start by calling `main` from python, then the next step is to convert `main` itself into python, but the functions it calls are still all C++.  Then you start converting functions called by main.  This way C++ never has to call python code.  You wouldn't rewrite any protocol code until you'd rewritten the code that uses it.

Comment: Where I falter: "Then you start converting functions called by main. This way C++ never has to call python code." Okay, I gradually convert the functions/classes called by main and work my way through. But main() isn't the only thing that uses these components, they hold dynamic information and are continually reused throughout the application, which is some sort of singleton design I think. It just seems like there'll be a mix mash of duplicate objects/classes, one in Python, one in C++ each containing information that the half needs but can't access. I guess this problem is beyond me.

Comment: Ben, hopefully this will illustrate my comprehension failure more clearly: http://dpaste.org/w4D1/ the state thing is just an example, don't read too much into the variable name.

Comment: @Josef: `obj2` doesn't even have a state variable.  But it seems that if you ported them in the other order, first `Object2` and then `Object1`, then you wouldn't have this problem.  Objects that are used all over the program are the last to be converted.  You might have to go depth-first, i.e. convert one of the functions called by main, then instead of porting another function called by main, convert a function called by the function already converted.  You're always looking for a class or function which is only used by python.

Comment: If you have a group of closely coupled classes and functions, you may have to port them as a group.  That's part of the reason that decoupling is so widely recommended.